# How to export object with Material created in render cycles to HTML file using Blend4Web correctly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, image, blend4web

I'm using Blend4Web in Blender 2.79. (It's not Blend4Web CE).
I applied one material, with UV Map Image Texture on my object, and I rendered it in Blender View, here the materials and texture was show normaly.
But when I export my object to HTML, using Blend4Web, an error occurs with the materials, and the image is not showed.

How can I solve this? What's the problem? My material was created in Blender Cycles, can this be the problem? Does Blend4Web work good with Cycles Materials?